# is there a way to generalise the number of arguments in a function type?

Tags: typescript

I have an alias for a function type definition:

```
IFn_1 = (_: any) => any
```

What I'd like to do is to generalise this into something like this:

```
IFn<n, out>
```

How would the template be defined where `n` is the number of arguments and `out` is the output type. The original definition then becomes:

```
IFn<1, any>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there were an easy way to generate a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) given its desired length as a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types), then this would be an easy question to answer.  Unfortunately, while this has been [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223), it's not part of the language yet.

Realistically the best we can do (without support for [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)) is to make our own type alias `TupleOfLength<N, V>` which produces a tuple of `N` copies of the value type `V` up to a hardcoded maximum number for `N`.   This is one way to do it:

```
type TupleOfLength<N extends number, V = any> = Extract<
  [
    [],
    [V],
    [V, V],
    [V, V, V],
    [V, V, V, V],
    [V, V, V, V, V],
    [V, V, V, V, V, V],
    [V, V, V, V, V, V, V],
    [V, V, V, V, V, V, V, V],
    // add more here if you need them
    ...V[][]
  ][N],
  any[]
>;
```

This works well when `N` is in the anticipated range:

```
type SixStrings = TupleOfLength<6, string>;
// type SixStrings = [string, string, string, string, string, string]
```

And not so well when it's not:

```
type AMillionBooleans = TupleOfLength<1000000, boolean>;
// type AMillionBooleans = boolean[] oh well
```

---

So let's take `TupleOfLength<N, V>` as a given and use it to define `IFn<N, R>`:

```
type IFn<N extends number, R = void> = (...args: TupleOfLength<N, any>) => R;
```

And let's see if it works:

```
type ThreeInStringOut = IFn<3, string>;
// type ThreeInStringOut = (args_0: any, args_1: any, args_2: any) => string

type NoneInNumberOut = IFn<0, number>;
// type NoneInNumberOut = () => number

type OneInAnyOut = IFn<1, any>;
// type OneInAnyOut = (args_0: any) => any

type GoogolInGoogolOut = IFn<1e100, 1e100>;
// type GoogolInGoogolOut = (...args: any[]) => 1e+100 o
```

Those all look fine, with the possible exception of when we pass a too-big number into `N`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-QC-2-NFbzNFoH0bQxV0giAAGpwL5SU-TUIA)